# Object oriented logic with different types for a report

Tags: java, c#, oop, design-patterns, interface

I want to create report mechanism with object oriented design patterns. I want to create a report generator.
Reports can be PDF , Wrod, HTML. So I created an interface like this:

```
interface IReportGenerator{
    Report Generate();
}

class PDFReportGenerator : IReportGenerator{
    public Report Generate(){
        retrun ******;
    }
}
```

But I have many type of reports. FeaturedProductsReport, MostActiveCustomersReport, BestSellerReporst, etc.

Each type of report is different parameters. So I could aggregate them. How can I do object oriented design these logic?

Comment: Sounds like you need to segregate the concerns. There is a difference between the CONTENT of the report, and the FORMAT in which it is rendered, so you probably need two interfaces - IAmAReportDefinition and IAmAFormatDefinition

Comment: Just use a `Dictionary <string,string>` and store the parameter names and values. Or if you need something more complex, create a custom class and use a `Dictionary <string, object>`

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this you really need to use 2 interfaces.

In particular you have your FORMATS, these are word, pdf, html, etc.

You also have some TYPES of reports: These are "Most Active Customer" "BestSeller" etc.

```
interface IReportFormat{
WriteReport(IReportType);
}

interface IReportType{
string Name{get;}
string GenerateReport();
}
```

You could alternatively make "GenerateReport" take teh IReportFormat and reverse the dependency.

Inside WriteReport with the above you need to get the generated string and then apply the Format specific formatting.  I am not familiar enough with the output formats to know what is different between them all, but conceivably you could implement GenerateReport in such a way that reads the special attributes of an IReportFormat and applies the transform all at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Abstract Factory design pattern.